# access header of page in httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

Using a httpmodule I want to add a meta tag to all pages in my web application at run time. So I need to access the header section of my page. How can I do this in a httpmodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better served by inserting this META tag into the header of your site's Master Page (and creating and using a Master Page if you don't already have one.) That give's you a central location for it, while not having the overhead of a module in the pipeline.

If you need to use an HttpModule, see this [link](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters) about installing a response filter.

Comment: Yes agreed that this would be better but situation dictates I need to use a httpmodule.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the HttpApplication and the current context of that so you can modify the request and response streams.